# sql command not properly ended in select

Tags: asp.net

I suffer the pbm while selecting data

```
    t = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
    m=Convert.ToString(DropDownList2.SelectedItem);
    n=Convert.ToString(DropDownList3.SelectedItem);
    o=Convert.ToString(DropDownList4.SelectedItem);
    {
     //da = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from " + t + "where area= '"+ m + "'and type='" + n + "'and ctype='" + o+"'" , con);
      cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from " + t + "where area='" + m + "'and type='" + n + "'and ctype='" + o+"'", con);
      dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: You probably need spaces:  ` " + t + " where` and `"' and type='", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add space between `t` and `where`

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from " + t + "where area='" + m + "'and type='" + n + "'and ctype='" + o+"'", con);
```

It should be like this

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from " + t + " where area='"+m+"' and type='"+n+"'and ctype='"+o+"'",con);                  

                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks fnd. bt "too many characters in character literal" error is arised

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `t` and `where` in `select * from " + t + "where [..]`.

My recommendation is some coffee ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between all concatenated value,

Please try my code instead of your code

```
cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from " + t + " where area='"+ m +"' and type='"+ n +"' and ctype='"+ o +"'",con);
```